# Can an Interface contain an ENum?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, interface

Can an Interface contain an Enum?

I am using asp.net 2.0. Suddenly my code started having problems when I added an enum to the interface below. In it, LookUpType is an enum.

```
Public Interface ILookup
    Property ID() As Int32
    Property Text() As String
    Property Description() As String
    Property Status() As Status
    Property OrderID() As Int32
    ReadOnly Property LookUpType() As LookUpType
End Interface
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're question is a bit ambigious, it sounds like you could be asking either of the following

### Can an Interface return a type which is an enum?

Yes.  Enum's are not special in any way that prevents them being a return type on an interface

### Can an Interface contain an enum definition?

Yes, this is completely legal in VB.Net.  It is however not legal in C#

```
Interface IFoo
    Enum E1
        V1
    End Enum
    Function SomeMethod() As E1
End Interface
```

Comment: When I look at this, all I see is bold questions. My eyes! :D

Comment: I can attest to the truthfulness of this difference between C# vs. VB.NET, but, I don't understand why it's this way. Still true in Oct 2019